# Watson Assistant Phone Integration Twilio

Tags: json, twilio, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to access user phone no in Watson assistant through the phone channel I am using Twilio sip trunks. from where the call is originated. It's written in the document that we can access phone integration context variables. But how can I do that especially the user contact number because we want to do verification based on phone numbers.

Link to document
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-phone-context#phone-context-variables-set-by-phone-channel
[image]